# Macro with SAPGUI Scripting : SAPLMEGUI:0013, the last number changes in each connexion to SAP

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have a macro which worked fine at first, until it's stopped working after deconnecting and reconnecting to SAP being connected for the second time.

I noticed that the issue is that, in each connection, this part of the SAPGui script changes: "SAPLMEGUI:0013", to be more specific, it's only the last number that changes each time.

I'm seeking for help as I still have difficulties finding the correct way to do it.
 I thought about doing something like this in order to resolve the issue(but it doesn't work):

```
sub verifyAddress()

'an Array to go through all the possible addresses
tabl = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

'Looking for the correct address
for i = Lbound(tabl) to UBound(tabl)
SAPLineToBeChecked = "wnd(0)/usr/subSUBO : SAPLMEGUI:001" & tabl(i) & "/subSUB2...."

'check the next address
on error resume next
session.findByID(SAPLineToBeChecked).cartePosition = 0
next
end sub
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: "SAPLMEGUI:0013" is the ID of the current screen. I think this [old question](https://answers.sap.com/questions/8689517/saplmegui-number-for-me22n-differs.html) is exactly what you experience. The solution is simply to retrieve the current screen so that you can use it to build the ID of fields: `var currentscreen = session.Info.Program & ":" & session.Info.ScreenNumber` (see [GuiSessionInfo](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiSessionInfo))

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reseponse, I tried t use this way but it didn't work for some reason: currentscreen =  session.Info.ScreenNumber then I replaced the screen id by the variable name currentscreen but it didn't work session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:00" & currentscreen & "/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1200/subSUB1:SAPLMEGUI:1211/tblSAPLMEGUITC_1211").Columns.elementAt(21).Selected = True

Comment: You're right, sorry for my incorrect answer, what I proposed was to retrieve the MAIN current screen and it's not relevant in your case. Instead, you may use the function created by Stefan [here](https://answers.sap.com/answers/13038950/view.html) and call it this way to get the object corresponding to "subSUB2..." and from there you may locate any inner field: `Set UserArea = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr") : Set Sub2 = FindByTypeName(UserArea, UserArea, "GuiSimpleContainer", "SUB2") ...`

Comment: Hi, Sandra is right, there is a solution from Stefan: https://answers.sap.com/questions/509361/how-to-tackle-the-changing-id-in-sapgui-scriptiing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve it is to try several screens (dynpro numbers) and catch errors. For example try for 0000 to 0099, ignore errors, and when found, use this one for the rest.
This is the way I do it (in python) for that type of cases. In Visual Basic should be possible but I do not use it anymore.

Alternatively you can use the answer from Stefan Schnell in the link below.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/684650/vb-scripting-what-is-the-rule-behind-the-numbering.html

Stefan is the author of the wonderful SAP Script Tracker tool.