# Not able to access "Local File" Export in SAP GUI using scripting

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

I am very new to Stack Overflow & VBA so please pardon me for any mistakes in my question.
We are trying to download a table into a .txt file from the SAP GUI interface using scripting

Whenever we try to run the code we get the error "the control could not be found by id".

The button which we are trying to press [image: screenshot #1]

Things we tried:

1. We tried using Send keys but we are not very confident on it. It will be our last resort.
2. When we used FindAllByName with "shell" it clicks the "Export" button on the table below it [image: screeenshot #2]

From what I can understand

1. The numbers (Italized or marked with ** in code) in the script keep changing. So we guess there is a clash between the stored script number in SAP and in the excel from which we are trying to run
2. The Table which we are trying to interact only appears when we load sum part numbers and hit "Go". It wont appear when we initially open the GUI.

   ```
       Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow _
   Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

   Sub SA_Dump()

   Dim App, Connection, session As Object
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Dim setFocus As Long
   Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
   Set Connection = App.Children(0)
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
   Dim wsh As Object
   Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim sCestaGrid As String

   Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy

   setFocus = session.ActiveWindow.Handle
   SetForegroundWindow setFocus

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

   'Reset fields
   session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 147, 25, False
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB01:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1005/subSUB01:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1001/btnRESETSIMPLESEL").press

   'hit selection window
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB01:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1005/subSUB02:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1002/btnSGNT_0000034-MATNR_V").press

   'hit copy from clipboard
   session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press

   'hit Check entries mark
   session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

   'hit Copy button
   session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press

   'hit Go button
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB01:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1005/subSUB01:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:1001/btnBUTTON01").press

   'Clear clipboard to avoid pop-up at end to close Excel sheets
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   'hit export (ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!)
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB02:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:*2119*/subSUB03:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:*2141*/cntlCONTAINER_7/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB02:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:*2119*/subSUB03:/SCF/SG/CA_110SPPDRPSB1:*2141*/cntlCONTAINER_7/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&PC"

   'hit Tick button
   session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

   'For rename
   session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "Rel_mvmnt.txt"
   session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10

   'Hit replace button
   session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13039407/how-to-upload-sap-table-from-excel-64x-with-vba.html?childToView=13038950#answer-13038950) is of any help, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557528/macro-with-sapgui-scripting-saplmegui0013-the-last-number-changes-in-each-co). And a [third link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/509361/how-to-tackle-the-changing-id-in-sapgui-scriptiing.html)

Comment: Hi Storax, Thanks for the comment. I had been working on this simultaneously while I posted the question. I fiddled around with the 'findallbyname' method.So I reaplaced the existing findallbyname method `session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("shell", "Guicollection").Item(1).ID` with `session.ActiveWindow.FindByName("shell", "Guicollection").ID`. And I got the desired address for the button I needed to click.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way and it works:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "%pc"
```

Let me know if it worked for you.